# flutter dropdown with items images, cant change value selected

Tags: dart, flutter

I've added a DropdownMenuItem, on my project, I was trying to everytime I click an item, it changes the value..but its not working..anyone encountered this approach and succeed?

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<int>> listSearch = [];

listSearch.add(DropdownMenuItem(
  child:Center(child: Image.asset("assets/ring.png", height: 30.0,width: 30.0,)),
  value: 0,
));
listSearch.add(DropdownMenuItem(
  child:Center(child: Image.asset("assets/hoo.png", height: 30.0,width: 30.0,)),
  value: 0,
));
listSearch.add(DropdownMenuItem(
  child:Center(child: Image.asset("assets/lock.png", height: 30.0,width: 30.0,)),
  value: 0,
));

Widget dropdownSearch(){
int search = 0;
String dropValue;

return DropdownButton(
  items: listSearch,
  //hint: listSearch[search],
  value: dropValue,
  onChanged: (value) {
    print('Selected item : $value');

    search = value;
    switch(search){
      case 0:
        print('clicks ring $search');

        break;
      case 1:
        print('clicks hoo $search');
        break;
      case 2:
        print('click lock $search');
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  } ,
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

1. Be sure your widget is `StatefulWidget`, not `StatelessWidget`. Please read https://flutter.io/tutorials/interactive/#creating-stateful-widget carefully.
2. The variable `dropValue` should be a class property, it's your state.
3. Make sure each `DropdownItem` has a different `value` set (e.g. 1,2,3).
4. In the `onChanged` handler, you will then use `setState(() => dropValue = value);` to update the state of the surrounding widget and `DropdownButton` will show the correct item selected.